# Clarifying "The man saw the woman with a telescope."?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

#### Cited from p. 12 of Introduction to Mathematical Thinking by Keith Devlin:

> **The man saw the woman with a telescope.**

> *Who had the telescope, the man or the woman?*

#### My question

Who, the man or the woman, had the telescope accoding to the 2 sentences below? Is it ambiguous?

2 sentences I came up with:

1. The man saw the woman, who was with a telescope.
2. The man saw the woman, having a telescope.

*Related post: [Does “The man saw the woman who is bringing the telescope” mean the woman is bringing the telescope?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/277495/127344)*

Comment: (1) definitely implies that the woman had the telescope (but _who had_ would be more natural). (2) is not very idiomatic English. It could conceivably mean "Because he had a telescope, the man could see the woman (from far away)".

Answer (score 1):

It is ambiguous (and is a well known example of an ambiguous sentence)

This is the point.  English has ambiguous sentences *that are only understandable in context*.  Also *every other natural language has ambiguous sentences!*

But when writing mathematically you need to be unambiguous.  (So how can you do maths if you need to express mathematical ideas in natural language?)

Answer (score 1):

The author is deliberately providing this as an example of an ambiguous sentence.

The phrase "with a telescope" could be modifying the noun "woman", or it could be modifying the verb "to see". A woman with a telescope is a woman who has a telescope. To see something with a telescope is to see it by using the telescope. So the two meanings are:

1. The man saw the woman who had a telescope.
2. The man used a telescope to see the woman.